# Node.js with websocket and cloudflare not working

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io, cloudflare

I have two node scripts connected with PHO site.
Domain is under Cloudflare protection.

I using node.js and socekt.io to update content live to all connected users, but when I using CF protection, node script not working well.

Could someone tell me what I should do? 
My ports: 8880 and 8080.

Comment: Do tou use http or https mode on CF? What did you receive in response, when try to connect to socket?

Comment: GET 522 ERROR and XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.domain.com:8880/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1486567242711-8. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://www.domain.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 522.

Comment: Ok, i see. Can you setup you socket.io server on port 80? You need to use domain.com/socket.io/

Comment: no i can't because I use PHP site on this port.

Comment: Could You explain: "domain.com/socket.io/"?

Comment: have u use nginx for php beckend? If you do, you have to add new location rule in server direction, like this location /socket.io {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8880/socket.io;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }

Comment: I use apache2..

Comment: Could You show me how to do this in apache2?

Comment: My recomendation - 
1. setup nginx for proxing (use 443 port for https)
2. then add dirrective for socket (proxy_pass ... to socket server port)
3. Turn on free https certificate on CloudFlare

Answer (score 0):

You need allow CORS from your node script add the following to your node script for socket.io.

io.set('origins', 'http://sampledomain.com:8880');